# SyntaxError: The requested module 'vue' does not provide an export named 'createSSRApp'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to create a `Vue` SSR app, and I'm following the instruction in their documentation [Server-Side Rendering (SSR)](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/ssr.html). However, I keep getting an error `SyntaxError: The requested module 'vue' does not provide an export named 'createSSRApp'` when doing`import { createSSRApp } from 'vue'`

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "SSR",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "vue": "^3.4.5"
  }
}
```

Here is my code on example.js

```
// this runs in Node.js on the server.
import { createSSRApp } from 'vue'
// Vue's server-rendering API is exposed under `vue/server-renderer`.
import { renderToString } from 'vue/server-renderer'

const app = createSSRApp({
  data: () => ({ count: 1 }),
  template: `<button @click="count++">{{ count }}</button>`
})

renderToString(app).then((html) => {
  console.log(html)
})
```

Comment: What is your Vue version?

Comment: The createSSRApp function is part of Vue 3, so make sure that you are using Vue 3 and have the correct version of the Vue package installed. I can see it in package.json please double check or install the package again or do `npm update`

Comment: @collab-with-tushar-raj my current `vue` version in `package-lock.json` is `3.4.5`

Comment: Can you remove `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` in your project?

Comment: @VivekVikranth I have deleted everything and started over at least twice. `Vue` version is 3.4.5 in package-lock.json. I did `npm update` and there was nothing to update

Comment: @collab-with-tushar-raj Done. Yet nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

I was initially using node version `14.15.2` when I upgraded to version `18.19.0` , it works normally